# Java inheritance(new to Java)

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm currently working on a project that consists in creating a simple software alike cloudShare.

We have 2 types of users, Basic and Premium. The basic ones only have 2GB of space while the Premium have 5GB.

Basic members can't share their documents with others but can recieve Premium members documents.

When a premium member shares a document with a basic member, the available space of the basic member is decreased by 50% of the whole document size, while Premium members can theoretically receive infinite shared documents that they will never run out of space.

On my CloudManager Class I have an array of Users(super class), so that I can save both Premium and Basic members on the same array.

The problem is when I try to share a document, I want to use the method shareDocument( that  exists in the BasicUser class and PremiumUser class, they're a bit different since on one method the space available is decreased).

But I'm unable to use the method since it doesn't exist in the superClass, only in the subclasses.How can I work around this?

Comment: add an `abstract` method to the superclass.

Comment: Please change your title to something that describes your issue. It is currently completely useless.

Comment: So why not add an abstract shareDocument method to the super class and override it in the sub classes?

Comment: I think what's a tad weird is that you say "Basic members can't share their documents" but then claim that `BasicUser` should have the `shareDocument()` method. If the way that sharing a document differs across many different types of users, some of which *can't* share, I'd go with an `interface DocumentSharing {...}`. Then "say" certain `User`s `implement DocumentSharing`.

Answer (score 1):

If all Users have a shareDocument method, then you should define it in the Users class. You can define it as an abstract method, which means that you must implement it in all subclasses, or you can provide a default implementation in Users and override it in the subclasses.

If not all Users have a shareDocuments method, then you may consider having your users implement an interface that does have the shareDocuments method and creating your collection of that interface type rather than Users.

If you insist on storing subtypes in a collection of a type that does not have the shareDocuments method, you can access it by specifically casting the contained objects to a type that has the shareDocuments method, but that is kind of a dicey maneuver here and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider redesigning User to be an abstract class. That way, you can use it to share methods across multiple classes. It would look something like:

```
public abstract class User {
   public User() {
      //common initialization junk
   }

   public abstract  Object shareDocument();
}
```

Now anything inherited from user can easily override the method `shareDocument` as well as call it.

Comment: Whoops sorry, was quickly answering :P. IDK what he return type would be so  I put object

Answer (score 0):

Although the most of the solutions suggested are correct & will work for now. I think the hierarchical design is not much flexible for change.

In future if you add another functionality or add another type of user then you might face issues.

I think better approach would be to use composition instated of inheritance.  Check out design patterns like command,decorator which will give you better idea.